# Center a image and a text in a button in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'd like to have a button with an image and a text centered.
The button is placed in the bottom of the screen.

I have this code :

```
<TouchableOpacity style={Styles.oneButton}>
    <View style={Styles.oneButtonView}>
        <Text style={Styles.payTextDollar}>
            <Image
                style={Styles.imageButton}
                source={props.image}
            />
            Pay
        </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>

oneButton: {
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#e41c23',
}

oneButtonView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
}

payTextDollar: {
    flex: 1,
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'MetaOffc-Light',
    textAlign: 'center',
}

imageButton: {
    marginTop: 6,
}
```

this works very well of iOS, however, the image is really small on Android, like so : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFWAy.png

Do you know anything about this behaviour ?
Do you know if there's another solution to have the image and the text centered in the button like so : https://i.stack.imgur.com/geBSz.png

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What are the styles you have set on your image?
Also you shouldn't have to nest image inside of text.  I'd pull that out and put it before text.

Comment: I edited my post, I added the image style. I know that put an image in a text is not conventional but If I put it outside I can't manage to center everything in the button.

Comment: @Kazuwa You may want to give your imageButton style a height and width.  Also look at using resizeMode in your style or on your <Image /> component to handle scaling.